# How does this callback works for a cakePHP component?

Tags: php, cakephp, callback, components

In CakeDC comments plugin for CakePHP [documentation](https://github.com/CakeDC/comments#component-callbacks) states that:

> ### Component callbacks
>
> It is possible to override or extend the most comments component
> methods in the controller. To do this we need to create method with
> prefix callback_comments Examples:
>
> callback_add will named as callback_commentsAdd in controller,
> callback_fetchData will named as callback_commentsFetchData in
> controller. ...

It works from the controller perfectly!:

> public function callback_commentsInitType() {
>
> ```
>     return 'flat'; // threaded, tree and flat supported
> }
> ```

I wonder, what is the new feature of [cakephp-2.0](/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.0) that allows you to do that? I need to understand how it was achieved to be able to implement such methodology in the future on my components.

Comment: https://github.com/CakeDC/comments/blob/ebe8c637c21ff12dfeb3a6a822af463096787608/Controller/Component/CommentsComponent.php#L622

Comment: Why you want to override the components  function if you want to override the function in another class then you should implement the functionality as plugin.

Comment: @VikashPathak Mainly, I need to understand what is happened in the CakeDC plugin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code of the component, if you look at the following function in [this](https://github.com/CakeDC/comments/blob/ebe8c637c21ff12dfeb3a6a822af463096787608/Controller/Component/CommentsComponent.php#L622) file (starting from line number 622):

```
/**
 * Call action from commponent or overriden action from controller.
 *
 * @param string $method
 * @param array $args
 * @return mixed
 */
    protected function _call($method, $args = array()) {
        $methodName = 'callback_comments' .  Inflector::camelize(Inflector::underscore($method));
        $localMethodName = 'callback_' .  $method;
        if (method_exists($this->Controller, $methodName)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array(&$this->Controller, $methodName), $args);
        } elseif (method_exists($this, $localMethodName)) {
            return call_user_func_array(array(&$this, $localMethodName), $args);
        } else {
            throw new BadMethodCallException();
        }
    }
```

You can see that the variable `$methodName` is being defined with prefix `callback_comments` and then the passed `$method` is appended to it after being treated by the `Inflector::underscore` and then `Inflector::camelize` method. The working of these is as follows:

1. `Inflector::underscore` will convert `initType` to `init_type`. Check doc [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector%3a%3aunderscore).
2. `Inflector::camelize` will further convert `init_type` to `InitType`. Check doc [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html#Inflector%3a%3acamelize).

Now, if `initType` was passed in the argument, then the `$methodName` will be:

`callback_comments` + `InitType` = `callback_commentsInitType`

After this, a `$localMethodName` is also being generated. In our `initType` example, it will be:

`callback_` + `initType` = `callback_initType`

After the names have been generated, it will simply search if the method exists in the attached controller and will execute it using `call_user_func_array` function by passing it and array with the object (in our case, the controller object (`&$this->Controller`) or the component object itself (`&$this`)) containing the method and the `$methodName` as first argument and then `$args` as second argument.

If the function was not found in the controller, then it will instead search in the component with `$localMethodName`. If it's found, then it is executed the same way.

Now how all this works is that the `_call` function is the single function used to call all the internal functions of the component, so that it will first check if the function has been overwritten in the controller, otherwise it will execute the function in the component itself.

You can check the component's beforeRender function [here](https://github.com/CakeDC/comments/blob/ebe8c637c21ff12dfeb3a6a822af463096787608/Controller/Component/CommentsComponent.php#L260) and you'll see how the `initType` function is called. In this case, if the controller contains a function named `callback_commentsInitType`, then it will be executed. Otherwise, the components `callback_initType` will be executed.

Hope this helps..